# Why access file is being ignored by Postfix?

Tags: email, postfix

I have installed Postfix, I can send mails between local users as expected, but I would try to limit the access of a particular user to the server. I edited the `/etc/postfix/access` file in this way:

```
diego@example.com REJECT
```

where example.com is `$mydomain`. I did also a `postmap access` to generate the validate file. Strangely, I can still send mail from the diego account using mutt. Here the maillog:

```
Jan 22 15:46:36 server postfix/pickup[6637]: 62117BF647: uid=500 from=<diego>
Jan 22 15:46:36 server postfix/cleanup[6737]: 62117BF647: message-id=<20140122144636.GA6732@server.example.com>
Jan 22 15:46:36 server postfix/qmgr[6638]: 62117BF647: from=<diego@example.com>, size=422, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 22 15:46:36 server postfix/local[6739]: 62117BF647: to=<localuser@server.example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.06/0.02/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jan 22 15:46:36 server postfix/qmgr[6638]: 62117BF647: removed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found finally the correct sintax. If you want to just block a user, you have to edit the main.cf file in this way:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
 check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
```

and in the access file:

```
user@                        REJECT
otheruser@server.example.com REJECT #this will REJECT only if sender is from server.example.com domain
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you also changed the Postfix configuration file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to look for restrictions:

```
check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
```

Then generate the hash file:

```
/usr/sbin/postmap /etc/postfix/access
```

Restart the `postfix` service:

```
service postfix restart
```

[Source](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html)

Example of `/etc/postfix/access` file:

```
all@my.domain   permit_mynetworks,reject
all@my.hostname permit_mynetworks,reject
```

[Other example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-blacklist-reject-sender-email-address/)

Comment: I did the modification you suggested in che main.cf file:

`check_recipient_access = hash:/etc/postfix/access`

and edited the access file:

`diego@example.com permit_mynetworks,reject`

but still I can send mails from the "diego" account.

Comment: You should only add **diego@example.com reject**. Then you need to execute the following command : **/usr/sbin/postmap /etc/postfix/access**

Comment: I did that also, I tried then:

`diego@ REJECT`

edited the `main.cf`:

`smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access`

and restarted postfix, but the account diego can still send emails.